# variable as a file name

Tags: c, file

Is it possible to use a variable as a filename in function fopen()? Can someone help with some example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a C string to pass into `fopen()`.  Just declare the string `char *` (I'd recommend using `const char *`) variable, set it and pass into the function.

```
const char *filename = "my/path/to/the/file";
FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Comment: Here I assume you mean to have a variable containing a file name.